# Replace several lines by one using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have an input like this:

```
This_is(A)
    Goto(B,condition_1)
    Goto(C,condition_2)

This_is(B)
    Goto(A,condition_3)

This_is(C)
    Goto(B,condition_1)
```

I want it to become like this

```
    (A,B,condition_1)
    (A,C,condition_2)

    (B,A,condition_3)

    (C,B,condition_1)
```

Anyone knows how to do this with sed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you don't **really** need to do this with sed, this will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ awk -F'[()]' '/^[^[:space:]]/{s=$2; next} {sub(/[^[:space:]]*\(/,"("s",")} 1' file
    (A,B,condition_1)
    (A,C,condition_2)

    (B,A,condition_3)

    (C,B,condition_1)
```

Comment: I wanted something that was basic unix. I thought sed was the tool but this is definitely the way to go. Thx

Answer (score 3):

This is a possible `sed` solution, where I have hardcoded a few bits, like `This_is` and `Goto` because the OP did not clarify if those strings change along the file in the actual file:

```
sed '/^This_is/{:a;N;s/\(^This_is(\(.\)).*\)\(\n *\)Goto(\([^)]*)\)$/\1\3(\2,\4/;$!ta;s/[^\n]*\n//}' input_file
```

(Unfortunately, with all these parenthesis, using the `-E` does not shorten the command much.)

The code is slightly more readable if split on more lines:

```
sed '/^This_is/{
                 :a
                 N
                 s/\(^This_is(\(.\)).*\)\(\n *\)Goto(\([^)]*)\)$/\1\3(\2,\4/
                 $!ta
                 s/[^\n]*\n//
               }' os
```

Here you can see that the code takes action only on the lines starting with `This_is`; when the program hits those lines, it does the following.

- It uses the `N` command to append the next line to the pattern space (interspersing `\n`s),
- and it attempts a substitution with `s/…/…/`, which essentially tries to pick the `x` in `This_is(x)` and to put it just after the last `Goto(` on the multiline,
- and it keeps doing this as long as the latter action is successful (`ta` branches to `:a` if `s` was successful) **and** the last line has not been read (`$!` matches all line but the last);

  - Indeed, this is a do-while loop, where `:a` marks the entry point, where the control jumps back if the while-condition is true, and `ta` is the command that evaluates the logical condition.
- When the above while loop terminates, the shorter `s/…/…/` command removes the leading line from the multiline pattern space, which is the `This_is` line.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^\S.*\(.*\)/{h;d};G;s/\S+\((.*\))\n.*(\(.*)\).*/\2,\1/;P;d' file
```

If a line starts with a non-white space character and contains parens, copy it to the hold space (HS) and then delete it.

Otherwise, append the HS, remove non-white characters upto the opening paren, insert the value between parens from the stored value, add a comma and print the first line and then delete the whole of the pattern space.

N.B. Lines that do not meet the substitution criteria will be unchanged.

An alternative solution using GNU parallel and sed:

```
parallel --pipe --recstart T -kqN1 sed -E '1{h;d};G;s/\S+\((.*)\n.*(\(.*)\).*/\2,\1/;P;d' <file
```